# Kruskal-Wallis Test effect size: Can it be greater than 1?

Tags: python, effect-size, kruskal-wallis-test

The Kruskal-Wallis Test effect size can be calculated based on the formulae from the [article](http://tss.awf.poznan.pl/files/3_Trends_Vol21_2014__no1_20.pdf),

> once the Kruskal-Wallis H-test has been computed, the epsilon-squared
> estimate of effect size can be calculated
>
> [image]

However, the effect size that I currently obtained by using the formulae above (with K-W Test statistic value using Python's `scipy.stats.kruskal`) is greater than 1.

```
from scipy import stats
n = len(X_train)
k = X_train["type_call"].nunique()
result = stats.kruskal(X_train["type_call"].astype("category").cat.codes, y_train)

print("size:", n)
print("number of groups:", k)
print("KW result:", result)
print("effect size:", result[0]/(len(X_train) - 1)) # simplify formulae

# Output
size: 28047
number of groups: 4
KW result: KruskalResult(statistic=43767.1470692367, pvalue=0.0)
effect size: 1.560548636855049
```

Shouldn't the effect size between the value of 0 and 1, where 0 indicates no relationship and 1 indicates strong relationship?

**EDIT**:
I also tried using an [online calculator](https://www.psychometrica.de/effect_size.html#nonparametric) to calculate the effect size and obtained the same result as my Python code.

[image]

Comment: "Shouldn't the effect size between the value of 0 and 1, where 0 indicates no relationship and 1 indicates strong relationship?" Why do you believe that?